selinux: file not reset as customized by admin to unconfined_u:object_r:public_content_t:s0
mkdir /files
touch /files/files{0..10}
semanage fcontext -a -t public_content_t "/files(/.*)?"
restorecon -v -R /files
semanage fcontext -a -t public_content_rw_t "/files(/files.*)?"
restorecon -v -R /files

An error:
/files not reset as customized by admin to unconfined_u:object_r:public_content_t:s0
/files/files10 not reset as customized by admin to unconfined_u:object_r:public_content_t:s0
/files/files8 not reset as customized by admin to unconfined_u:object_r:public_content_t:s0
/files/files5 not reset as customized by admin to unconfined_u:object_r:public_content_t:s0
/files/files4 not reset as customized by admin to unconfined_u:object_r:public_content_t:s0
/files/files9 not reset as customized by admin to unconfined_u:object_r:public_content_t:s0
/files/files0 not reset as customized by admin to unconfined_u:object_r:public_content_t:s0
/files/files7 not reset as customized by admin to unconfined_u:object_r:public_content_t:s0
/files/files1 not reset as customized by admin to unconfined_u:object_r:public_content_t:s0
/files/files3 not reset as customized by admin to unconfined_u:object_r:public_content_t:s0
/files/files2 not reset as customized by admin to unconfined_u:object_r:public_content_t:s0
/files/files6 not reset as customized by admin to unconfined_u:object_r:public_content_t:s0

Ls
ls -Z /files:

Output:
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root unconfined_u:object_r:public_content_t:s0 

0 Aug 30 00:47 files0
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root unconfined_u:object_r:public_content_t:s0 0 Aug 30 00:47 files1
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root unconfined_u:object_r:public_content_t:s0 0 Aug 30 00:47 files10
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root unconfined_u:object_r:public_content_t:s0 0 Aug 30 00:47 files2
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root unconfined_u:object_r:public_content_t:s0 0 Aug 30 00:47 files3
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root unconfined_u:object_r:public_content_t:s0 0 Aug 30 00:47 files4
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root unconfined_u:object_r:public_content_t:s0 0 Aug 30 00:47 files5
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root unconfined_u:object_r:public_content_t:s0 0 Aug 30 00:47 files6
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root unconfined_u:object_r:public_content_t:s0 0 Aug 30 00:47 files7
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root unconfined_u:object_r:public_content_t:s0 0 Aug 30 00:47 files8
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root unconfined_u:object_r:public_content_t:s0 0 Aug 30 00:47 files9


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

When restoring context, you want to use the -F flag:
-F     Force reset of context to match file_context for customizable files, and the default file context, changing the user, role, range portion as well as the type.

You can then retry with:
restorecon -RFv /files

It should work.

I do nothing, but the error has dissapeared
